How to disable persistent connection of KerioControl VPN client in linux
I've installed KerioControl VPN client on UBUNTU 22.04 and configured it with no problem, but it restarts the connection when I stop it using sudo /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc stop.
I think it's because of <connection type="persistent"> in config file.
With this type I should disable the connection by changing <active>1</active> to <active>0</active> and reload the config file every time, but there should be a better way.
In windows client there is a checkbox to enable/disable persistent connection, but in linux there is no GUI and it's configured using CLI.
Is there any other type of connection or a better way to prevent reconnecting?
